# Configure webserver for compression

Tags: apache-httpd, compression, gzip

Based on this page: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html#GzipCompression

I need to enable compression on my website.

Comment: I assume by your tags that you're using Apache on some Linux distribution. It might be helpful to provide a little more background information, and what you've looked at already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start googling words 'apache compression'. First link in SERP will lead you to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html